# Getting unexpected error request: GET when trying to integrate ionic app with couchDB via flask

Tags: angularjs, flask, ionic-framework, couchdb

I am trying to build an app on ionic using AngularJS. I am building my backend on couchdb. I am using flask as the web server.

Up until this point, I had created mock json files and was using these along with `$httpBackend` to simulate a couchdb response on the front end.

I built the couchDB database using python couchdb (I've given a sample dataset below):

```
{
    '_id':'3f2d02d3fd1e4e69bce1e07ba9edad6c',
    '_rev':'3-065502dd64f489f243c00df23514d8e6', 
    'name':'aabc fffu', 'age': '27', 'username' : 'galeej'
}
```

My design document for the database (_design/listDependents):

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.username, doc)
}
```

Note that this has been done on desktop couch (if that is indeed the correct terminology - please do correct me if I'm wrong)

I then created a simple python program:

```
@app.route('/dependentshow/', methods = ['GET'])
def getUsers():
    userView = g.couch.get('_design/listDependents')
    getUserById = ViewDefinition('_design/listDependents', 'listDependents', userView['views']['listDependents']['map'])
    users = []
    for row in getUserById():
        users.append(row.value)
    return Response(json.dumps(users), mimetype = 'application/json')
```

I am able to see the database I created on my local couchdb when I access `127.0.0.1:5000/dependentshow`

However, when I try to access it using my front end ionic app, I get an unexpected error.

I have set my `restangular.baseurl` to 127.0.0.0:5000.

I have also used a passThrough given below:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/dependentshow').passThrough();
```

This is the log of my error:

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: Unexpected request: GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/dependentshow
>   No more request expected
>   at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1406)
>   at sendReq (ionic.bundle.js:23645)
>   at serverRequest (ionic.bundle.js:23357)
>   at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
>   at ionic.bundle.js:27895
>   at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
>   at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
>   at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
>   at ionic.bundle.js:31030
>   at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18706)

Thanks in advance for any help. I have tried searching quite a bit, but being new to this, I have had some trouble getting the correct results.

Comment: I looked at the possibility of encountering a CORS error... but even that did not help.  I went to the flask website and imported the crossdomain function that was wrttien.  It works from the back end perspective, but i still get the error.

Comment: Hi Everyone, it actually did turn out to be a CORS error.  There are two ways of doing this: one, you can download a google chrome extension that enables CORS (which is really a short term fix).  A long term fix on the flask side is to add the following lines of code: `@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
 response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
 response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
 response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
 return response` after app = Flask(__name__)